# Why does godbolt show parameter being passed in edi if C++ uses cdecl calling convention?

Tags: c++, godbolt

[image]

Why does godbolt (gcc 9.3) show parameter being passed in edi if C++ uses cdecl calling convention? I can't find anything on this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RBP` and `RSP` are 64-bit registers, which means your code is being compiled for 64-bit, not 32-bit.  `cdecl` is a 32-bit calling convention, it simply does not exist in 64-bit.  On 64-bit systems, the first few integer-sized parameters are passed via registers, not the call stack.

On non-Windows platforms ([godbolt runs on Amazon EC2 instances using Ubuntu](https://xania.org/201609/how-compiler-explorer-runs-on-amazon)), the first 6 integer-sized parameters are passed via the `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, and `R9` registers, respectively.  `EDI` is bytes 0-3 of `RDI`, and `int` is 4 bytes in your compiler, so you see the `num` parameter being passed via `EDI`.

On Windows platforms, the first 4 integer-sized parameters are passed via the `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, and `R9` registers, respectively. `EDI` is not used for passing parameters.

See [Stack frame layout on x86-64](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64)  for more details.

Comment: Probably should have seen this as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JohnBap I did see that, actually. But I didn't mention it since godbolt doesn't run on Windows, and also because the doc I did link to in my answer links to the MSDN docs.